# How to print Hijrah months in java?

Tags: java, monthcalendar, hijri

Any enum to associate below months?

```
1 Muharram
2 Safar
3 Rabi\u02bb I
  Rabi\u02bb II
  Jumada I
  Jumada II
  Rajab
  Sha\u02bbban
  Ramadan
  Shawwal
  Dhu\u02bbl-Qi\u02bbdah
  Dhu\u02bbl-Hijjah
```

Comment: FYI, in modern Java: [`HijrahChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase//21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Time4j](http://www.time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/HijriMonth.html) library, calendar project.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>time4j-calendar</artifactId>
    <version>4.24</version>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```
Stream.of(HijriMonth.values()).forEach(v->
            System.out.println("Display name: " + v.getDisplayName(Locale.US) + " month index: " + v.getValue()));
```

Output:

```
Display name: Muharram month index: 1
Display name: Safar month index: 2
Display name: Rabiʻ I month index: 3
Display name: Rabiʻ II month index: 4
Display name: Jumada I month index: 5
Display name: Jumada II month index: 6
Display name: Rajab month index: 7
Display name: Shaʻban month index: 8
Display name: Ramadan month index: 9
Display name: Shawwal month index: 10
Display name: Dhuʻl-Qiʻdah month index: 11
Display name: Dhuʻl-Hijjah month index: 12
```

Comment: Thx but don't want to depend on other library thought to do same using java 1.8+ api

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no built-in enum in Java, although there now a bunch of usefull classes in java 8 like `HijrahChronology`, `HijrahDate`, `HijrahEra`. If you don't want to use other libraries then you should write your own enum. But it might be difficult after all)